# Navigator always start with route '/'

Tags: flutter

The route `'/'` keeps being automatically pushed to the Navigator on the start of the application.

Let's start with [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) example of the official docs.

Everything works fine but if you change `'/'` to `'/home'` (change made both to `initiaRoute` and `routes`) we get the following error:

```
The requested route name was: "/home"
The following routes were therefore attempted:
* /
* /home
This resulted in the following objects:
* null
* MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(RouteSettings("/home", null), animation: null)
 One or more of those objects was null, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and
"/" will be used instead.
```

**Question 1**: I'm explicitly defining `'/home'` as the initialRoute, why it's insisting to go to `'/'`?

---

I tried to fix the error by adding a blank page for `'/'`.
The error was 'fixed' and the app was starting on the correct page, but the widget tree was looking like this:
[image: widget_tree]

Container is the "blank page" I created associated with `'/'` and still being pushed. For even more confusion it's on the top of the navigation stack!

**Question 2**: Why `FirstScreen` is being shown instead of `Container`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This caught me out, too. If you look at the documentation for the [`initialRoute` property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html):

> If the route contains slashes, then it is treated as a "deep link", and before this route is pushed, the routes leading to this one are pushed also. For example, if the route was /a/b/c, then the app would start with the three routes /a, /a/b, and /a/b/c loaded, in that order.

What the example fails to explain is that `/` is also pushed. So if your `initialRoute` is `/home` then it first pushes `/`, then it pushes `/home`.

The (thankfully very simple) fix is to use routes that don't start with `/`, so in your case, just `home` :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's kind of design as [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/10894) mentioned.

> The main purpose of this PR is to make it so that when you set the
>   initial route and it's a hierarchical route (e.g. /a/b/c), it
>   implies multiple pushes, one for each step of the route (so in that
>   case, /, /a, /a/b, and /a/b/c, in that order). If any of those
>   routes don't exist, it falls back to '/'.