# Using `home` property with `initialRoute` in MaterialApp

Tags: flutter

Could you explaine how does this navigation works?

Why the app start starts with the `LoginPage` opened? Does it mean that `initialRoute` property shadow the `home` property in the `MaterialApp`?

If to make `pop` from the `LoginPage` then the `HomePage` will be opened. Does it mean that `HomePage` was opened before the `initialRoute` was launched?

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: const HomePage(),
      initialRoute: '/login',
      onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
);

Route<dynamic>? _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name != '/login') {
      return null;
    }

    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => const LoginPage(),
      fullscreenDialog: true,
    );
}
```

That is shown here
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-flutter-codelabs/blob/102-starter_and_101-complete/mdc_100_series/lib/app.dart

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official documentation, we should use either the `initialRoute` or the `home` property:

```
 Warning: When using initialRoute, don’t define a home property.
```

[Source](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

Comment: look at the link I posted

Comment: I saw the link, however, open-source repositories can and do contain mistakes. Usually, the official documentation is the source of truth we should follow.

Comment: that's interesting because the code I posted is also the official as it relates to the flutter codelabs

Comment: Sure is, the idea behind open source is that countless developers can audit the code, and mistakes are found and can be fixed quickly. In this case, opening a Github issue and outlining your finding will be of great help to the community!

Answer (score 0):

About the [home property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/home.html)

> The widget for the default route of the app (`Navigator.defaultRouteName, which is /`).
> This is the route that is displayed first when the application is started normally, unless initialRoute is specified. It's also the route that's displayed if the initialRoute can't be displayed.

But more interesting thing is about pop and from the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html)

> If the route name starts with a slash, then it is treated as a "deep link", and before this route is pushed, the routes leading to this one are pushed also. For example, if the route was /a/b/c, then the app would start with the four routes /, /a, /a/b, and /a/b/c loaded, in that order. Even if the route was just /a, the app would start with / and /a loaded. You can use the onGenerateInitialRoutes property to override this behavior.

My understanding is app is starting with `initialRoute`, while the `home`property is also  treat like root `/`, on last pop it will be at `home`.

You can also check [Navigator always start with route '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56468319/10157127)

The [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) configures the top-level Navigator to search for routes in the following order:

1. For the / route, the home property, if non-null, is used.
2. Otherwise, the routes table is used, if it has an entry for the
   route.
3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called, if provided. It should return
   a non-null value for any valid route not handled by home and routes.
4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.